# Extracting Code from an Android App

Tags: android

Over the last couple of months, i've been working on an android mobile application. Last night my laptop crashed, and I lost all the files relating to it. However, I do have the application installed on my Android device from when I was testing it. Is there any way to extract the source code from the file on my device so that I don't have to rewrite all my code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but whether or not you get this code back, consider this a lesson in why off-site backups are critical. Save your code up to somewhere like Github, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: We have no way to know that you are being honest and talking about your own app.  This community is mainly a community of software developers who do not like people violating license agreements.  Therefore, you are unlikely to get help here.  There are plenty of sites where people who don't care so much discuss reverse engineering applications.  Please try those.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: "Here, children, we have an example of why external version control is so important."

Answer (score 3):

Get the source code of any Apk.. 
just upload the apk and this site 
will give you the source file of that 
http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Comment: Contrary to what some have said, there are legitimate reasons for using a tool like this.  For example, the PHBs decided that I was going to integrate a library that was very poorly documented.  I had to reverse-engineer it to find out what parameters I was supposed to pass to some of the methods.